# Finding $|a|$, a complex number, given a system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

$a$ and $b$ are complex numbers where $|2a - b| = 25$, $|a + 2b| = 5$, and $|a + b| = 2$.

Using the information, find $|a|$.

I tried using the magnitude formula (i.e. where $|a| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$), but it became messy very quickly. Is there a simpler way?

*precalculus*

Comment: Have you tried using $z\overline{z}=|z|^2$?

Comment: @xaviermo2: For what equation would I use that identity?

Answer (score 0):

$|2a-b|^2 = 25^2 = 625 \to (2a-b)(2\overline{a} - \overline{b}) = 625 \to 4|a|^2-2(\overline{a}b+\overline{b}a)+|b|^2=625$,

$|a+2b|^2=5^2=25 \to (a+2b)(\overline{a} + 2\overline{b}) = 25 \to |a|^2 + 2(\overline{a}b+\overline{b}a)+4|b|^2$.

Adding these equations: $5(|a|^2+|b|^2) = 650 \to |a|^2+|b|^2=130\tag{1}$

$|a+b|^2=4 \to (a+b)(\overline{a}+\overline{b}) = 4 \to |a|^2+|b|^2+ a\overline{b}+b\overline{a} = 4\to a\overline{b}+b\overline{a} = 4-130=-126 \to 4|a|^2-2(-126)+|b|^2=625\to 4|a|^2+|b|^2=625-252=373\tag{2}$

$(1), (2) \rightarrow 3|a|^2 = 373-130 = 243 \to |a|^2 = 81 \to |a| = 9$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**
$$|2a - b|^2 = (2a-b)(\overline{2a-b})=(2a-b)(\overline{2a}-\overline{b})=4a\overline{a}-2a\overline{b}-2\overline{a}b+b\overline{b}=4|a|^2-2a\overline{b}-2\overline{a}b+|b|^2=625$$
$$|a+2b|^2=|a|^2+2a\overline{b}+2\overline{a}b+4|b|^2=25$$
therefor
$$5(|a|^2+|b|^2)=650$$
and from $|a+b|=2$ we get,
$$|a|^2+|b|^2+\overline{a}b+\overline{b}a=4$$